# Octopus Deploy - Getting a resolved value of a variable

Tags: .net, configuration, f#, octopus-deploy

I'm creating a .NET application that needs to get some data from Octopus. Here's my code (F#):

```
let endpoint = new OctopusServerEndpoint(<OctopusServerAddress>, <OctopusApiKey>)
let repository = new OctopusRepository(endpoint)
let variables = repository.VariableSets.Get(project.Link("Variables")).Variables
let myVariable = variables |> Seq.tryFind (fun variable -> variable.Name = "MyVariable")
myVariable.Value
```

The problem is the Value contains references to other variables, e.g.

```
HostAddress = https://*:443/#{Octopus.Project.Name}
```

Is there a nice way to get this resolved by Octopus, or do I need to solve the problem manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently variables are only evaluated as part of a deployment and there is no API for evaluating variables. The best approach would be to scan for references and replace them yourself.

If you want, you can also suggest the feature on the [Octopus Deploy Uservoice site](https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I thought it was impossible, but wasn't sure - that for help. I'll suggest the feature.
For now I've got an idea about how to implement variables resolving as a recursive function. The problem in my case is that I store some of the variables in "Project Variables" section, some in a shared library, and moreover I use "*" in HostAddress, so I need to learn a machine name as well. Perfectly doable, but requires some work ;).

Comment: Do you know if they have finally got around to creating a feature for this?